# CSS zoom property destroying font's outlook

Tags: javascript, css

I have an issue with zooming in and out multiple elements with CSS zoom property, hard to explain it without showing the actual effect so I uploaded this on youtube:
[here it is](https://youtu.be/aZlIx7EDO1A)

I would like the font to zoom smoother than this, hopefully. 
I've tried using scale property here but it ruins positioning, these are my current functions:

```
let zoom_param = 1;
function zooming_out(on_off) {
if (on_off == 0) {
    if (zoom_param >= 0.1) {
    zoom_out = setInterval(function() {
            blocks.style.transition = 50 + 'ms';
            blocks.style.zoom =  zoom_param;
            side_blocks.style.transition = 50 + 'ms';
            side_blocks.style.zoom =  zoom_param;
            zoom_param -= 0.001;
        }, 5);
    }
} else {
    clearInterval(zoom_out);
}
}
function zooming_in(on_off) {
if (on_off == 0) {
    zoom_in = setInterval(function() {
            blocks.style.transition = 50 + 'ms';
            blocks.style.zoom =  zoom_param;
            side_blocks.style.transition = 50 + 'ms';
            side_blocks.style.zoom =  zoom_param;
            zoom_param += 0.001;
        }, 5);
} else {
    clearInterval(zoom_in);
}
}
```

they are called by a mousedown and mouseup events (idk if it is important),
Thanks for help!

Comment: Looks like you'll have to use a canvas instead.

Comment: How does scale ruin your positioning? Please show your scale code

Comment: And could you share a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS property zoom is not well supported. Try it with transform instead. No timers needed, the animation will be smooth as well. Hope this code snippets can help you.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.element');
element.style.transition = 'transform';
element.style.transitionTimingFunction = 'linear';
element.style.transformOrigin = 'left top';
element.style.transitionDuration = '2s';

let zoomMin = 1;
let zoomMax = 2;

document.querySelector('.zoom-in').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 zoomingIn();
});

document.querySelector('.zoom-stop').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 zoomingStop();
});

document.querySelector('.zoom-out').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 zoomingOut();
});

function zoomingStop() {
 let scaleX = element.getBoundingClientRect().width / element.offsetWidth;
  element.style.transform = 'scale(' + scaleX + ', ' + scaleX + ')';
}

function zoomingIn() {
 element.style.transform = 'scale(' + zoomMax + ', ' + zoomMax + ')';   
}

function zoomingOut() {
 element.style.transform = 'scale(' + zoomMin + ', ' + zoomMin + ')';  
}
```

```css
div {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #0095ff;
}
```

```html
<button class="zoom-in">zoomIn</button>
<button class="zoom-stop">stop</button>
<button class="zoom-out">zoomOut</button>

<div class="element">
  <p>Some</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```